# Node form validations

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node and building a simple book library app with express and mongodb. My forms work fine but I have having trouble with form validations. I initially used express validator but seems the code I wrote from the older version and it's legacy now. The problem is there are so many frameworks(Joi, express validator with joi, form input validator) and I am little confused now. One good thing with Java/Spring is that you don't have so many options. Can you please suggest what should be the best way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are two kinds of form validations, from server-side and client-side how do you want to validate your form ?

Comment: Server side form validations. Thanks for asking this, I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of form validations client-side and server-side If you want to validate from server-side. You can use another node package to validate your form,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-validate

if you want to validate from client-side you can use `jQuery` plugin,

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Not looking for client side plugins. I looked into the form-validate plugin which seems to be updated around 2013 and don't see any new changes after that.